# Reverse itemgetter (itemsetter?): inserting a list of items into specific positions in a larger list

Tags: python

I need to correct some values in a list. I am using itemgetter to extract the values into a smaller list. Afterwards I need to insert the items I corrected into the larger list. Is there a way to use the itemgetter in reverse to insert a list of values into a larger list at specific positions? If not, is there a more concise way of inserting the elements that does not require one line per insertion?

```
get_data = itemgetter(*indexes)

line_as_list = line.split(",")
data = list(get_data(line_as_list))

# Change the elements in the list "data"
```

My current way of inserting the items afterwards is

```
line_as_list[index1] = data[0]
line_as_list[index2] = data[1]
...
```

which creates a lot of boilerplate code. Is there a better way? I am hoping for something like

```
itemsetter(line_as_list, data, indexes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `itemsetter` in the standard library, but it's easy to write:

```
def itemsetter(*items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        item = items[0]
        def g(obj, value):
            obj[item] = value
    else:
        def g(obj, *values):
            for item, value in zip(items, values):
                obj[item] = value
    return g
```

Example:

```
lst = range(10, 20)
indexes = [1,3,5,7]

data = [81, 83, 85, 87]
setter = itemsetter(*indexes)

setter(lst, *data)
print lst # [10, 81, 12, 83, 14, 85, 16, 87, 18, 19]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can assign to a splice:

```
>>> big=[1,2,3,4]
>>> small=[1.5, 1.7]
>>> big[2:2]
[]
>>> big[2:2]=small
>>> big
[1, 2, 1.5, 1.7, 3, 4]
```

and also if it's not empty:

```
>>> big=[1,2,3,4]
>>> small=[1.5, 1.7]
>>> big[2:3]=small
>>> big
[1, 2, 1.5, 1.7, 4]
```

Comment: Neat trick, but I do not see how it is an itemgetter in reverse.

Comment: what is the necessity of "itemgetter in reverse".  This works cleanly and instantly. Ulrich's is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
    line_as_list[index] = data[i]
```

This was simple. Sorry for asking.

Comment: Better: `for index, item in zip(indexes, data)...`

Comment: If you add that as an answer I will upvote and accept.

Answer (score -1):

use splices

```
original = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

insert_element = ['foo']

insertion_index = 5

new_list = original[:insertion_index] + insert_element + original[insertion_index:]

print new_list
```

Comment: This is kinda tedious for several hundred items though, but thanks.