# Multiple keys per value with special requirements

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this example with `d` an existing dictionnary:

```
x = d['a'] = d['b'] = d['c'] = (1, 2) # Too verbose
```

What I would like is something like:

```
x = d['a','b','c'] = (1, 2) # Would be ideal but yields d[('a','b','c')]
```

However this does not reproduce the example cause it assigns a tuple `('a','b','c')` as key.

I know the `.update()` or `dict.fromkeys()` methods but neither fit. For the first it does not return anything and for the second it creates a new dict in addition to not returning `(1,2)` to x.

In short, I want such expression:

```
x = ... = (1,2)
```

Which will assign `(1,2)` to keys `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'` in `d` still returning the value to `x`.

This is for a lecture / an attempt to maximize consistency and readability in my code.

Comment: This sounds like a reversed [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522490/reverse-itemgetter-itemsetter-inserting-a-list-of-items-into-specific-positi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a class that inherits from `dict` and does what you want, like this example:

```py
class MyDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            for arg in key:
                super(MyDict, self).__setitem__(arg, value)

d = MyDict()
x = d["a", "b", "c"] = (1, 2)
x == d["a"] == d["b"] == d["c"] == (1, 2)  # True
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, that is what I was affraid of. A custom class may unfortunately be confusing... Still if there is no solution using built-in stuff I will accept your answer.

Comment: No problem; I think that's the closest thing to your request, but then you have to introduce classes and inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is a function that's kinda like a reversed
[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), an "itemsetter" (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522490/reverse-itemgetter-itemsetter-inserting-a-list-of-items-into-specific-positi), which, however, is about lists) - something along the lines of

```py
def itemsetter(*keys, value, target):
    for k in keys:
        target[k] = value

d = dict()

# set keys a, b and c in d to (1, 2)        
itemsetter('a', 'b', 'c', value=(1, 2), target=d)

# Result: {'a': (1, 2), 'b': (1, 2), 'c': (1, 2)}
```

This is not exactly the syntax you wanted, but it might be a good compromise.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. As you mentioned it is not exactly the thing (I am pretty sure it is undoable anyway). Still it will be a good piece for a dict itemsetter!